# Can't access to Azure VM since restart

Tags: azure

I can't access to my VM since I restart that VM. I can't access via SSH, HTTP, or any way. I have all the endpoints settings correctly.

I read about this issue, and is not a common issue, but also is not inusual. I'm afraid to lose all my information. Any help?

Comment: I had this happen to a Linux VM of mine a while back and was able to get more information by attaching the OS drive to another new VM instance, then reading the log information from the system. This might be a way for you to recover data at least in the worst scenario, if you're afraid that booting the OS drive again might be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the underlying VHD associated with your VM, take a copy of that and try creating a new instance. Keep a backup of your VHDs at regular intervals if the information/data/setup is too critical.